# Confusion about conserved current in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, conservation-laws, field-theory

In classical mechanics, it is known from Noether's theorem every continuous symmetry gives a conserved current
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0,
\end{equation}
where $J^{\mu}$ (generally) can be written in terms of fields and their conjugate momentum. The conserved charge $Q$ is
\begin{equation}
Q=\int d^3x J^0
\end{equation}
In quantum case, our fields are promoted to operators. So $J^{\mu} \rightarrow \hat{J^{\mu}}$, $Q\rightarrow \hat{Q}$. Conservation of $\hat{Q}$ means $d\hat{Q}/dt=-i[\hat{Q},\hat{H}]=0$, where $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian.

My question is: How to write $\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}=0$ in quantum case? Do we have $\partial_{\mu}\hat{J^{\mu}}=0$ or $\langle\alpha|\partial_{\mu}\hat{J^{\mu}}|\alpha\rangle=0$ for any ket $|\alpha\rangle$?

Answer (score 4):

The quantum version of *the Noether theorem* is *Ward-Takanashi identity* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity.
It gives relationships between correlation functions in the QFT :
$$
\langle \partial^{\mu} j_{\mu} (x) \mathcal{O}_1 (x_1) \ldots 
\mathcal{O}_N (x_N) \rangle = 
\sum_{n = 1}^{N} \delta(x - x_n)\langle \mathcal{O}_1 (x_1) \ldots \delta \mathcal{O}_n (x_N) \ldots 
\mathcal{O}_N (x_N) \rangle
$$
Where $\delta$ denotes the variation, induced by the conserved charge $Q$ :
$$
\delta \mathcal{O}_n (x_N) = i [Q, \mathcal{O}_n]
$$
This identity can be derived rather shortly via the path integral formalism.

Answer (score 4):

We should have the *operator* equation $\partial_\mu \hat J^\mu=0$. This implies that $\langle a|\partial_\mu \hat J^\mu|b\rangle=0$, $\forall a,b$.

Comment: The condition $\langle a|\partial_\mu \hat{J}^\mu|b\rangle=0,\quad\forall a,b$ is not stronger that $\langle a|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|a\rangle=0,\quad\forall a$. They are equivalent. Indeed, if you assume the second one is true, then playing around with both $0=\langle a+b|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|a+b\rangle$ and $0=\langle a-b|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|a-b\rangle$ one can show the first.

Comment: No, I am not. The statement is $0=\langle a|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|a\rangle$ for all kets $|a\rangle$ in the Hilbert space is equivalent to $0=\langle a|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|b\rangle$ for all kets $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$ in the Hilbert space. What you are saying would be: $0=\langle a|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|a\rangle$ for all kets $|a\rangle$ in a basis of the Hilbert space is equivalent to $0=\langle a|\partial_\mu\hat{J}^\mu|b\rangle$ for all kets $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$ in the Hilbert space.

Comment: In words, he's saying that the vanishing of the diagonal in every basis implies the operator is zero.

Comment: I agree with @Iván Mauricio Burbano. My original statement was wrong. I was thinking only of a single basis.

Comment: @mikestone I would edit the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are all fine, but they don't give you the commutator formula you seem to be seeking.

Just like
$$
\frac{d}{dt} Q = - i \hbar [Q, H],
$$

the generators of the translation group (4-momentum) give you space-time derivatives in QFT:

$$
\partial_{\mu} J^{\mu} = - i \hbar [J^{\mu}, P_{\mu}],
$$

with $P_{\mu} = (E, -\vec{P})$.

So your quantum Noether equation is an operator equation
$$
\sum_{\mu = 0}^4 [J^{\mu}(x), P_{\mu}] = 0.
$$